# How to move all folders in a directory with mv and bash variables

Tags: bash, directory, mv

I wanted to take paths to directories from files that we got from a user as parameters of function and from files extract the paths and move all files and folders in the source directory to the destination directory, but something went wrong: It writes to me, that "No such file or directory"

With this input

[image]

Where dest_adr.txt contains this path: C:\Users\Michal\Desktop\tmp and source_adr.txt contains this path: C:\Users\Michal\Desktop\test\

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_WITH_ADRESS_TO_BLENDER_PATH=$1
FILE_WITH_ADRESS_TO_FOLDER_WITH_ADDONS=$2

function move_folders(){    
    mv "${PATH_TO_FOLDER_WITH_ADDONS_}"/* "${PATH_TO_BLENDR_DIRECTORIE_}"/
}   

if [  $# -eq 0 ]
  then
      PATH_TO_BLENDR_DIRECTORIE="C:/Program Files/Blender Foundation/Blender 3.0/3.0/scripts/addons"
      FOLDER_WITH_ADDONS="none"
      echo $PATH_TO_BLENDR_DIRECTORIE
      echo $FOLDER_WITH_ADDONS
  else  
      PATH_TO_BLENDR_DIRECTORIE_=$(cat $FILE_WITH_ADRESS_TO_BLENDER_PATH | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' -e 's/\C://g')
      PATH_TO_FOLDER_WITH_ADDONS_=$(cat $FILE_WITH_ADRESS_TO_FOLDER_WITH_ADDONS | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' -e 's/\C://g')
      echo $PATH_TO_BLENDR_DIRECTORIE_
      echo $PATH_TO_FOLDER_WITH_ADDONS_
      move_folders
  fi
```

Comment: Did you checked that test/ has still files, if you ran the script, they will be all already moved to your destination

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just place the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just place the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: "folders" and "directories" are different things.  Everything you are talking about here is a directory.  The word "folder" has no place anywhere in this question.

Comment: Folders are also called "directories," and they are created on the hard drive (HD) or solid-state drive (SSD) when the operating system and applications are installed. Files are always stored in folders

Answer (score 0):

Use [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
adrian@pc:/tmp/move> path_to_file=/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1.gz
adrian@pc:/tmp/move> folder_path=${path_to_file%/*} 
adrian@pc:/tmp/move> echo $folder_path 
/usr/share/man/man1
adrian@pc:/tmp/move> file_name=${path_to_file##*/}
adrian@pc:/tmp/move> echo $file_name 
bash.1.gz
```

Don't use cat to send variable, it will send content of file no path, use echo or printf instead.

Answer (score -2):

The error occurs because the `test/` directory is **empty**.

Try again with files within it. It's expected behavior to fail with a wildcard if you don't have files in the source directory you are trying to move.

Edit:
Or use `mv -r`

Comment: The directory has a few folders inside from the very beginning :(

Comment: Well use move with `-r` to recurse over your folders

Comment: output of `tree` of the test/ folder ?